# Warning: \oval, \circle, or \line size unavailable

Tags: color, fancybox

I have been trying to have a border for a whole page I am trying to write in LaTeX and I have used the following two lines:

```
\thisfancyput(3.25in,-4.5in){%
\setlength{\unitlength}{1in}\fancyoval(8.2,10.5)}
```

from the package `fancybox`. It worked well, but I keep getting the warning:

```
myDocument.tex:70:\oval, \circle, or \line size unavailable on input line 118.
```

My questions now are:

- How may I get rid of this warning?
- How to thicken the border line?
- How to change its color?

Here is my Latex file

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fancybox}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{pict2e}
\usepackage[tableposition=top]{caption}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage[cm]{fullpage}
\usepackage[margin=0.4in]{geometry}
%\usepackage{multicolumn}
\usepackage{rotating}
\def\wl{\par \vspace{\baselineskip}}
\definecolor{LimeGreen}{RGB}{64,186,65}
%%%%%%%%% Background %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\newcommand\BackgroundPic{
\put(0,-70){
\parbox[b][\paperheight]{\paperwidth}{%
\vfill
\centering

\vfill
}}}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%% FRAME STARTS HERE  %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\thisfancyput(3.25in,-4.5in){%
\setlength{\unitlength}{1in}\fancyoval(8.2,10.5)}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%  FRAME STARTS HERE  %%%%%%%%%%%%%%


%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Document Starts Here:  %%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
\AddToShipoutPicture{\BackgroundPic}

 \thispagestyle{empty}
 \vspace{-0.75cm}
 \textbf{\footnotesize {\color{LimeGreen}XXX XXXX\\}}

 \vspace{-0.5cm}
\hrulefill%\dotfill

\begin{center}
\normalsize
  \underline{Some words go here}\\
  \vspace{1.0cm}
  \large{Something else here}\\

  \vspace{0.2cm}

  \vspace{0.9cm}

 \end{center}

\begin{center}


Something else here
\end{center}
\wl
\wl
\hrule

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Did you try loading the `pict2e` package?

Comment: Hi,

Thank you for the replies.
This box does not allow me to paste my "myDocument.tex". It limits the number of characters one can write.
I have already add \usepackage{pict2e} but it did not work.
I will appreciate it if you can tell me how may I add my LaTeX file.

Comment: Based on info from the comment box, I will add my latex file in my original post. I hope this will help.

Comment: The warning happens when `\fancyoval` calls `\@getcirc` and in the computations the resulting number is bigger than 10. Since `fancybox` directly calls `\@getcirc`, it doesn't profit of `pict2e`. Using `\oval` avoids the warning.

Comment: @egreg
replacing \fancyoval with \oval worked like charm.
Is there a way to make the border thicker and change its color?

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

The `\fancyoval` macro of `fancybox` is responsible for the warning. Its origin is an attempt at overriding a limitation in the `\oval` macro of `picture` mode.

However, quarter circles can have only a maximum radius, with the standard `picture` mode, and this usage of `\fancyoval` computes a radius bigger than available. Nowadays, `pict2e` makes `\fancyoval` less good than `\oval` that also has an extended syntax (check the documentation). So my advice is to forget about `\fancyoval` and use `\oval` directly.

You can also change the color and the line thickness, for instance with

```
\thisfancyput(3.25in,-4.5in){%
  \setlength{\unitlength}{1in}%
  \linethickness{3pt}%
  \color{red}\oval(8.2,10.5)%
}
```

Change the thickess and color to suit.

Comment: It worked! That's exactly what I wanted.